# What is an invalid path according to fnmatch?

Tags: php, path, posix

I'm using `fnmatch()` to match some simple expressions in PHP because it's a lot more performant and simpler than using `preg_match()`. I'm running this over 15GB of data, so performance matters. However, for some strings (I don't know which) I get the warning:

```
PHP Warning: fnmatch() expects parameter 2 to be a valid path, string given in /some/path/file.php on line xx
```

I understand `fnmatch` is closely related to paths and the system it runs on (it's only available on POSIX-systems) but the documentation for the second parameter describes it as:

> string
>
> The tested string. This function is especially useful for
>   filenames, but may also be used on regular strings.
>
> The average user may be used to shell patterns or at least in their
>   simplest form to '?' and '*' wildcards so using fnmatch() instead of
>   preg_match() for frontend search expression input may be way more
>   convenient for non-programming users.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php

So there seems to be a bug in either PHP or the documentation. But regardless of that, it would help a great deal if somebody knew what caused this warning.

What do `fnmatch()` consider to be an invalid path?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to run a var_dump(). This error message could come up when a path has a null byte, mainly for security reasons. If that doesn't work, check the length of the string and make sure it is what you'd expect, just in case there are other invisible bytes.

Comment: The problem is I can't run a var_dump on 15GB of data. I don't know when the problem occurs. There is no way to find out if this occurred, other than to use output buffering and check that it's empty after calling this function. Also, I like your profile picture.

Comment: You're right...I missed that "15GB" :/. If you don't know where it happens maybe you can use a try->catch block, so you can printout (or collect) exactly the strings that are causing the issue. I know it's not a solution, but could at least give you some hints. For the profile picture, well, thanks :D